# Excel VBA Code to move data from 4 specific cells to another worksheet in the next available row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have been learning about VBA code but this has me stuck. I am using Excel-2013.
I have 4 cells in my "Invoice" sheet (Cells E3, C3, E36, and E34) that I want to transfer to my "Method of Payment" Sheet in the next available row. The first row that will be available is the 3rd row.
I would like Cell E3 to copy into column C, C3 into D, E36 into E, and E34 into F.
When each invoice is saved I want this data to transfer. I already have code clear my invoice. I just need to transfer these 4 data cells.

Comment: Please share what you already have (only what is relevant for your question) and also what have you already tried. If you've learned VBA I suppose you've already tried something. Also, we would need to understand better your problem to be able to help.

Comment: I don't have code for this function- but I have solved it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Sub CopyDataToMethodOfPayment()
    Dim NewRow: NewRow = GetFirstEmptyRowOnMethodOfPayment     'Find the next row free on "Method Of Payment"
    Worksheets("Method Of Payment").Cells(NewRow, 3).Value = Worksheets("Invoice").Range("E3").Value    'Copy E3 to Column C on empty row
    Worksheets("Method Of Payment").Cells(NewRow, 4).Value = Worksheets("Invoice").Range("C3").Value    'Copy C3 to Column D on empty row
    Worksheets("Method Of Payment").Cells(NewRow, 5).Value = Worksheets("Invoice").Range("E36").Value   'Copy E36 to Column E on empty row
    Worksheets("Method Of Payment").Cells(NewRow, 6).Value = Worksheets("Invoice").Range("E34").Value   'Copy E34 to Column F on empty row
End Sub

Function GetFirstEmptyRowOnMethodOfPayment() As Integer
    Dim RowCount: RowCount = 1 'Set row to start looking for empty rows from
    Do
        RowCount = RowCount + 1 'Increment to next row
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Method Of Payment").Cells(RowCount, 3).Value) 'Stop once we find an empty one
    GetFirstEmptyRowOnMethodOfPayment = RowCount    'Return the row number of the empty one
End Function
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully and I was able to add it to my current code  and call it so I can save, make a pdf and print, and then clear my invoice all at the same time. Much appreciated. On final problem to solve and I think the program will be up and running.

Comment: @Jen Glad it helped :) When you're confident your problem is solved, don't forget to click the tick next to an answer that helps you

Comment: @Junno Wondering if you can help. I am getting a error code now on your  "LOOP UNTIL" line. It is telling me the subscript out of range. I have looked up why that might happen but I don't know what has changed. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jen Did you amend anything? Which line throws the error? The sheet is still named "Method Of Payment" and the column with data is still C?

Comment: I Yes to both. No change

Comment: Loop until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Method Of Payment"). Cells (ROwCount, 3). Value is the line that is throwing the error

Comment: @Jen Subscript out of range means it can't find something in an array. The only array used here is the `Worksheets("Method Of Payment")` part (I can replicate the behaviour if I *don't* have a sheet with that name.) Could you just double check it's exactly the same, maybe go to rename the sheet and copy and paste it into VBA again to be sure it exactly matches?

Comment: Too funny. I renamed the exact same and it worked. Not sure why it worked this time. Thanks.

Comment: @Jen Bizarre. Now you know for next time at least :)

Comment: @Junno Wondering if I can get your help with another code. I have it listed as another question but I think I am making it too complicated. just like this one I want cell data from specific cells to move to others but this time based on a date range and one specific cell data. if you are willing it would be great to have help.